# Is log(n^c) equal O(log(n))

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

Does `log(n^c)=O(log(n))` such that c is a constant?

I think this is true as  `log(n^c)/log(n)<=C2`

so `c<=C2`. Is this true? If not what is true?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because you can convert it to

[image]

Comment: Can you write Latex on stackoverflow.com? On stats.stackexchange.com you can.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 for some reason SO thinks that programmers shouldn't know/use math. So no you can't write it here (you can on math, stats and other sites). The way I do it is writing, printscreening and pasting an image.

Comment: @SalvadorDali haha sums it up. btw do you use Word's equation editor?

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah I use this stuff: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php . It is limited from UI point of view, but you can type any latex formula and get the image.

Answer (score 2):

log(n^c)=clog(n)

log(n^c)/log(n)=c(log(n)/log(n))=c